# Can I share SQLite database between a desktop application and my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sqlite, synchronization

I am writing an application that two parts. A desktop application runs on the desktop (probably an AIR app) and the iPhone application which runs on the iPhone. I am new to iPhone development.

Both apps would work off exactly the same sqlite database. Ideally I would like to somehow copy the sqlite database file to the mobile applications's Documents folder and work with it there, and vice versa taking advantage of iTunes sync.

How exactly do I do this? Is there a better practice way to run sync between the phone and desktop app? If so are there any examples of how best to do it?

Most solutions I have found assume the database is stored in a separate format such as MySQL and that the data would need to be serialised and deserialised somehow. I just want to try and use the same file and copy the file over.

Comment: I guess the other thing here is as stated above I am quite new to iPhone development. I could rephrase that question as how do I best communicate between my two applications? Should I set up a webserver in the desktop app and then have the phone appliciation connect to it over http? Or can I gain access to the phone database through iTunes? If so how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is a single-user database.  If you go the "copy the database" route, then you risk losing data.  If the desktop user added data and the iOS user added data, someone's data will be lost when you copy the file.

You can implement your own "syncing" algorithm that identifies changes between the databases and keeps them in sync.  This can be a pain, but is a common solution and is what I would recommend.  I've done it this way for a desktop/iOS app.

You can choose to use a database server, but this will require network access to connect to it.

Comment: So how do you then suggest I then communicate between the two applications? Would prefer not to need internet access.

Comment: As I said, I would recommend the "sync" method, but it requires that the two devices are on the same wifi network at least.  They won't need internet access, if that matters.